# Import external data connections into Excel 2013 for use in Excel 2003

Tags: microsoft-excel, compatibility, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2003, sql

I have a workbook in Excel 2013 that retrieves data from a SQL database via a query. However, the connection imports data as a table, which is incompatible with Excel 2003. Is there a way to convert the table to a range for use in Excel 2003, while keeping the data connections intact? Or is there another way of using data connections so they are imported as a range in the first place?

EDIT: I forgot to mention I need to retain the query so it can be refreshed and data kept up to date.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try saving the file from Excel 2013 in Excel 97-2003 format (.xls).  This should down-grade the table to just a range but keep the Data Connection.

If that doesn't work you could start in Excel 2003 and rebuild the Data Connection e.g.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/training/quick-reference-card-RZ001183132.aspx?section=13&mode=print

If that doesn't work you could upgrade to Excel 2013 for around USD 100 ...

Comment: Thanks Mike, I don't personally have Excel 2003 - I write reports for colleagues that only have Excel 2003, whereas I have Excel 2013. I have asked that people be upgraded to 2003, but this has not been approved. I've tried your suggestion of just saving the file as .xls, but my colleagues say they cannot refresh the data.

Comment: Just a quick update - I've recently found out my colleagues were opening the file in read-only mode, and that this was the issue, rather than anything to do with the data connections. Thanks again for your help!